# Click an array element, show the element with the same index of another array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

I have a list of elements which is plotted via a `ng-repeat` and I am using a `ng-click` to get the index of the element of the array I am clicking on.

This is the html code:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="period in periodPercentage" ng-click="getIndex('{{period}}')">
    {{period}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

And this is what is inside the controller:

```
$scope.periodPercentage = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$scope.getIndex = function(period) {
  console.log($scope.periodPercentage.indexOf(period));
};
```

In another part of the code, I am using again an `ng-repeat` to show the elements of another `array` with the same length.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="ratio in ratioPercentage">
    {{ratio}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to show only the `{{ratio}}` with the same index of `{{period}}` via `ng-show` and hide the other ones?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: where is the code that displays the "other" array?

Comment: I am going to update my question, but the way is plotted is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that:

```
<li ng-repeat="period in periodPercentage" ng-click="getindex($index)">
    {{period}}
</li>
```

and

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="ratio in ratioPercentage" ng-show="$index == findex">
    {{ratio}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

[see updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ep6cqvue/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not adding anything to my previous code. Maybe could you edit your answer?

Answer (score 3):

It may help you.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="testrahul">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(i,period) in periodPercentage" ng-click="getindex(i)">
    {{period}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
function testrahul($scope) {
$scope.periodPercentage = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$scope.getindex = function(i){
    console.log(i);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="period in periodPercentage" ng-click="setvariable($index)">
    {{period}}
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="ratio in ratioPercentage" ng-show="someVariable == $index">
    {{ratio}}
  </li>
</ul>


function setVariable(index){ $scope.someVariable = index;}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is this:

```
  $scope.periodPercentage = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  $scope.ratePercentage = ['arate', 'brate', 'crate', 'drate'];
  $scope.rateShowPercentage = angular.copy($scope.ratePercentage);
  $scope.update = function(index){
    $scope.rateShowPercentage  = [$scope.ratePercentage[index]];
  }
```

In the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="GreetingController">
<ul >
  <li ng-repeat="period in periodPercentage" ng-click="update($index)">
    {{period}}
  </li>
</ul>

<ul >
  <li ng-repeat="rate in rateShowPercentage" >
    {{rate}}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qYPtZqCM3g2vpDMK1NWE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Somehing like:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="object in list" ng-click="openOther($index)">
    {{object.data}}
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="object in otherListToShow">
    {{object.data}}
  </li>
</ul>

and:

var otherList = [ some data ...]
 var otherListToShow = []

openOther(index){
listToShow.push(otherList[index])
}
```

Comment: You should use the $index variable!

Answer (score 0):

you need to give $index into ng-click

```
 <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="period in periodPercentage" ng-click="getIndex('{{$index}}')">
  {{period}}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an easier way to get the index, thanks. But how do I `ng-show` it in the other array?